# python jedi, autocompletion for dynamic attribute

Tags: python, getattr, python-class

I'm trying to write a class. Objects of that class can take a label/value pair and store it in such a way that `label` can be accessed as an attribute, returning `value`: `obj.label -> value`

The main goal here is to get autocompletion in jupyter notebooks, so `obj.<tab>` should produce the list of labels as autocompletion suggestion. The below class accomplishes this:

```
class Autocompleter:
    def __init__(self, ):
        self._funcs = {}
    
    def add(self, label):
        self._funcs[label] = 1.
        
    def __dir__(self):
        return list(self._funcs.keys())
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in dir(self):
            return self._funcs[name]
```

The problem: When accessing an invalid attribute, the `__getattr__` simply returns `None`. I'd rather have it throw an exception. I can think of 2 ways to achieve this, but unfortunately both break the autocompletion:

Changing `__getattr__` to:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self._funcs[name]
```

or

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in dir(self):
        return self._funcs[name]
    else:
        raise Exception('invalid name')
```

produces the desired exception, but breaks the autocompletion:

```
a = Autocompleter()
a.add('foo')
```

Now `a.<tab>` does not suggest `foo` for autocompletion, it simply does nothing. As far as I can tell, jedi is used by default for autompletion in jupyterlab.
**Question:** Is there a way to get both the exception on invalid names and the autocomplete feature working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The correct way to handle an invalid attribute name is to raise an AttributeError. This can then be understood by jedi.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in dir(self):
        return self._funcs[name]
    raise AttributeError(name)
```

Note that the `__dir__` method is still needed.